# PreparedStatement setNull with java.sql.Types.NULL

Tags: java, jdbc

When setting a `null` value,
Should we always use the value
`java.sql.Types.NULL`?
Does the following code work for all types?:

```java
preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.NULL);
```

Why would someone choose to use another type like so?:

```java
preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: Does `preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.NULL);` work for any types? The spec says it needs to be the type of the column, but different drivers may handle things differently.

Comment: Some database drivers might be picky, or some database drivers might not support `Types.NULL`, or in some database drivers it might be more efficient to use `setNull(1, Types.BOOLEAN` vs `setNull(1. Types.VARCHAR)`. The thing to keep in mind is that JDBC is an **API**, and although a lot of things are specified, there is enough room for differences between drivers (either because the specification gives that room, or because of misinterpretation of the specification, or because a driver implementation runs into limitations of the database they're talking to).